# UIImage in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have scrollview of `CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 266)` with an image in it. Image has features like scaling and zoom. But when I drag the image to the bottom or top, it disappears behind the scrollview, it's not viewable. I want to bind that image in a manner that it does not disappear.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ([super initWithFrame:frame] == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    appDelegate = (PostCart1AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    originalSize = frame.size;
    originalTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    touchBeginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    self.exclusiveTouch = YES;

    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSMutableSet *currentTouches = [[[event touchesForView:self] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [currentTouches minusSet:touches];
    if ([currentTouches count] > 0) {



        [self updateOriginalTransformForTouches:currentTouches];
        [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:currentTouches];
    }
    [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:touches];
}

CGPoint fr;

-(BOOL)checkFrameinBounds:(TouchImageView *)t
{

    float x = [touch1 locationInView:self].x; 
    float y = [touch1 locationInView:self].y;    
    NSLog(@"touch x = %f",x);
    NSLog(@"touch y = %f",y);


    if((fr.x < 30 || fr.y < 30) ||  (fr.x > 265 || fr.y > 240))
    { 
        NSLog(@" NO ..  fr.x = %f",fr.x);
        NSLog(@" NO ..  fr.y = %f",fr.y);
        return NO;  
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@" YES ..  fr.x = %f",fr.x);
    NSLog(@" YES ..  fr.y = %f",fr.y);
        return YES;
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    touch1 = [touches anyObject];
    fr=[[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    if ([self checkFrameinBounds:self])
    {
    CGAffineTransform incrementalTransform = [self incrementalTransformWithTouches:[event touchesForView:self]];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(originalTransform, incrementalTransform);

     [self setConstrainedTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(originalTransform, incrementalTransform)];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([self checkFrameinBounds:self]) 
    {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (touch.tapCount >= 2) {
            [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
        }
    }

    [self updateOriginalTransformForTouches:[event touchesForView:self]];
    [self removeTouchesFromCache:touches];

    NSMutableSet *remainingTouches = [[[event touchesForView:self] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [remainingTouches minusSet:touches];
    [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:remainingTouches];


  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the image gets autoreleased? Did you try to retain it?

Comment: Yes i am retaining the image. Application is not crashed. Bur image get's disappeared.

Comment: @DipakSonara how exactly have you implemented the dragging of the image? Can you please provide that code?

Comment: Show us your code and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Please check the code.. i might got the solution.. thank for your time.

Comment: Close the question then.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen while scrolling you are changing the bounds of the image view.Then the frame of the image view will be changed with reference to the device screen boundaries.To have the image view always inside the scrollview you have to change the frame of the image view then its frame will be changed with reference to its parent view that is scrollview.